# Displaying Mediapicker field in blogpost.list.cshtml in Orchard CMS

Tags: blogs, orchardcms

I'm trying to edit the page when my blog displays the `Parts.Blogs.BlogPost.List.cshtml`. I went to `ContentItems` under content and added a `MediaPicker Field` called `BlogPostImage` to my BlogPosts, and I also made an alternate to `Parts.Blogs.BlogPost.List.cshtml` in my theme (which is the file I'm editing. The code that I have in there is:

```
@using Orchard.ContentManagement;
@{
IEnumerable<object> blogPosts =
    Model.ContentItems;
}
@if (blogPosts == null || blogPosts.Count() < 1)

{
    <p>@T("No posts.")</p>
}
else
{
    int count = 0;
    <div id="Blog">
        <div id="slides">
            <div class="slides_container">
                @foreach (dynamic post in blogPosts)
                {
                    count++;
                    string title = post.ContentItem.TitlePart.Title;
                    ContentItem item = post.ContentItem;
                    string text = post.ContentItem.BodyPart.Text;
                    string postImageUrl = post.BlogPostImage.Url;
                    <div class="slide">
                        <a href="@Url.ItemDisplayUrl(item)"><img src="@postImageUrl" width="625" height="400" alt="Slide @count.ToString()"></a>
                        <div class="caption" style="bottom: 0">
                          <h4><a href="@Url.ItemDisplayUrl(item)">@title</a></h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>      
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I cannot however figure out how in the world to call that mediapicker field into my list. Any way I try it comes back blank with some kind of querystring in the href. Something like "?23423455657". I took off the variable and that querystring still shows up. What I'm basically trying to accomplish is to put these into a slideshow, with the jquery to start the slideshow in the `layout.cshtml`. TIA

//SOLUTION:

After days and days of reading and researching I finally found a working solution.

Replacing:

```
string postImageUrl = post.BlogPostImage.Url;
```

With:

```
string postImageUrl =  ((ContentItem)post.ContentItem).Parts.SelectMany(p => p.Fields).Where(f => f.Name == "BlogPostImage").First().Storage.Get<string>(null);
```

Got it from here: http://blog.cloudconstruct.com/post/Creating-a-rotating-image-gallery-in-Orchard-CMS.aspx

I hope it helps anyone stuck in the same boat. I am still curious why I couldn't simply call it the way I had it, but it's working now! :)

Comment: This can be greatly simplified:
`dynamic postItem = post.ContentItem; var postImageUrl =  (string)postItem.BlogPost.BlogPostImage.Url;`

Comment: Ahhh! so that's what I was missing! .BlogPost! I thought I was already at that level with @foreach (dynamic post in blogPosts). Thanks for clarifying that Bertrand!

Comment: Let me add that as an answer then.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the image url using dynamic:

```
dynamic postItem = post.ContentItem;
var postImageUrl = (string)postItem.BlogPost.BlogPostImage.Url;
```

Content item, when used as a dynamic object, exposes all its parts (here we're using the part that has the same name as the type, and where the fields are added when adding them from the admin). The part itself has dynamic members for each field (here, BlogPostImage), and from there you can get to the field's properties (Url here).

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above answer with version 1.7 with no joy. I ended up having to download a copy of the source so I could delve into the objects. The below code got me the information I needed and also will help in future when I add extra fields to other content. I used part of the above answer to get to my solution...

```
IEnumerable<object> blogPosts = Model.ContentItems.ContentItems;
foreach (dynamic post in blogPosts) {
    dynamic q = ((ContentItem)post.ContentItem).Parts.SelectMany(p => p.Fields).Where(f => f.Name == "BlogPostImage").First();
    string postImageUrl = q.MediaParts[0].MediaUrl;
    <img src="@postImageUrl" />
}
```

Hope this helps somebody.